# Installing feature in wso2 apim

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

How do i install Logging management feature in wso2 apim version-3.1.1 using pom file.

I tried from official doc in below link:
https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/85376969

But I'm facing dependency conflict.

Comment: WSO2 does not support feature installation in later versions. The article you are referring to is an old one. (2017) Although a pom installation might succeed sometimes, it's not recommended.

Comment: Yes we no longer host wso2 feature repository in public versions. However you may copy the jars related to the feature and still achieve it.